# Segmentation fault while storing values inside a strucure from other structure using C

Tags: c, structure

I have two structures

```
typedef struct profile_datagram_t
{
    unsigned char *src;
    unsigned char *dst;
    unsigned char ver;
    unsigned char n;
    struct profile_t profiles[MAXPROFILES];
} header;

header outObj;

struct pearson_record
{
    unsigned char *src;
};
```

Now i want to memcpy the value inside outObj.src into unsigned char *src of struct pearson_record.

How to do this?? Any kind of example or any help would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you allocated memory to your structure elements using malloc ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `outObj.src` points to valid memory which contains a null-terminated string:

```
struct person_record x;
x.src = malloc(strlen(outObj.src) + 1);  // +1 for the null terminator!
strcpy(x.src, outObj.src);               // could have used strncpy as well
```

Comment: i still get segmentation fault.

Comment: Well, probably that's because person_record.src doesn't point to a valid string, either -- you can't copy it until you actually initialize it to something.

Comment: @Kerrek: Sorry, no, I wasn't talking to you -- your answer's perfect. I was talking to the original poster. If `outObj.src` contains garbage, then they'll still get a segfault using your code. I got the struct names backwards in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to realize is that the `struct`s contain pointers to character strings; they don't contain any space for the character strings themselves. You can't use `memcpy()` because there isn't any destination memory to copy into.  One way to do this would be to use `strdup()`:

```
header h;
struct pearson_record p;
p.src = "the source";
h.src = strdup(p.src);
```

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of the possibility that the `char*` points to a read-only string... depending on the lifetimes involved, perhaps one might get away with literally just assigning `p.src = h.src;`...

Answer (score 0):

```
outObj.src = (unsigned char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
pearson_record = (unsigned char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
memcpy(pearson_record.src, outObj.src, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you created `outObj` or an instance of `pearson_record`, you have pointers that don't point to anything. You have to make them point to some buffer in memory before using them.

```
outObj.src = malloc(length);
// do something with outObj.src

struct pearson_record prec;
prec.src = malloc(length);
memcpy(prec.src, outObj.src, length);

// do something with them

// free memory allocated by malloc
free(outObj.src);
free(prec.src);
```

where `length` is the length of the data.

Comment: I am still getting segmentation fault.

Comment: @user537670 you can't expect us to help you with your segmentation fault if you don't show us the code causing it. This is obviously not it.

Comment: link to my full code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184667/segmentation-fault-while-transferring-data-to-a-berkeley-db